# How to copy files from iPhone to Windows PC?

Tags: iphone, windows, file, file-transfer

First time iPhone user and this does not exactly seem like a straightforward process.

I have a number of files on my iPhone that I'd like to copy over to my MS Windows PC. Most of them live in the Downloads folder on my phone.

When plugging in the phone via USB to my PC and opening iTunes I see I can transfer some media, but nothing about any other files.

I've tried solutions like snapdrop.net but I'm copying about 50gb worth of stuff and snapdrop seems to just stop working after a period of time. Also tried Airdroid but it doesn't look like it can "see" my Downloads folder.

Why can't I just see my files in the File Explorer on Windows? The iPhone just has a drive with files on it after all.

Is it possible to get the files off my iPhone and onto my PC?

Comment: Have you tried the Files.app on the iPhone? Does that work? Generally Apple does not provide unrestricted access to the iPhone file system, even on a PC. If the Files.app does not do the trick you may need to use something like iMazing.

Comment: iPhone apps (and their content) is highly sandboxed. iMazing will give you maximum access to iPhone content.

Comment: See this [Apple Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/itunes/transfer-files-itns32636/12.12/windows/10) for moving files between your PC and your device.

Comment: iMazing does appear to have this capability but I'm not going to pay $40 to access my own files...it's incredibly confounding to me that I can't just simply copy the files from one device that I own to another. I guess they are just locked in my iPhone and only my iPhone unless I can figure out where I downloaded them in the first place and redownload them from my PC.

Comment: have you looked for some file manager/explorer app? I use the free version of one, for my needs ok.

Comment: @Andra which one do you use?

Comment: @intA [FE File Explorer](https://www.skyjos.com/fileexplorer/)